# nginx redirections like htaccess

Tags: php, nginx

I wanna remove from my url adress .php and redirect from example.com to www.example.com 
How can I this make in nginx? 
Thanks a lot!

```
server {
#listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
#listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

root /usr/share/nginx/www;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server_name example.com;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

}


location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#non-www to www solution

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name website.com;
        return 301 $scheme://www.website.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.website.com;
        ... 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer!!
Do I need restart nginx after change ?

Comment: Restart after changes made in a config file. In your case use `nginx -s reload`. That should do the trick.